# Kinect v2 with java

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, javacv, kinect-v2

I have a Kinect version 2 . I recently understand that javacv library is available for java developers to do their projects. Now, is there any solution to get Kinect version 2 images in  javacv?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Java for Kinect](https://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/),it handles both Kinect V1 And V2 but it ask to have some skill in Java